# ¿Puedo actualizar un estado en el hook "useEffect" de esta forma?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Tengo una aplicación SPA, para saber si un usuario está logueado, estoy intentando actualizar una variable con `useState` dentro de un `useEffect` que tiene como dependencia `useLocation` pero la aplicación se renderiza 2 veces (`React.strickMode` está comentado)

¿Cómo podría hacer para que no se renderice mas de una vez cuando cambio de ruta?

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  //<React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  //</React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import { Route, Routes, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import Dashboard from "./Components/Dashboard";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  console.log("Render App")
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState(false)
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user);
    setUser(true); // En mi aplicación, el valor sale de un método asíncrono
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <button onClick={() => navigate("/")}>Home</button>
      <button onClick={() => navigate("/dashboard")}>Dashboard</button>

      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Si estas usando react 18, useEffect hace doble re-render en dev, más [aquí](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#my-effect-runs-twice-when-the-component-mounts)

Comment: Tengo entendido que eso ocurre con la etiqueta "StrickMode", pero la tengo comentada

Comment: Quita el location del arreglo de dependencias, pues esto es lo que hace que cada vez que eso cambie ese useEffect se dispare.

Comment: Necesito tener ese arreglo, la cuestión es que desconozco porque se renderiza 2 veces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente ya entiendo como funciona `useEffect`, en primer lugar se renderiza el componente, luego llama a `useEffect`, y se vuelve a renderizar.

Por lo que la opción mas sencilla es poner un condicional en la ejecución del `useEffect` de forma que una vez que se haya renderizado el componente, se ejecuta dicho `useEffect` una única vez, para esto he tenido que cambiar la dependencia por una variable en lugar de un hook como es `useLocation()`

Espero que a alguien le sirva.